# How to read webpage values from static C# in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, static, webmethod

I am trying to read the value of a field on a webpage from a static function in C# using AJAX. My question is: What is the line of code I must use in my C# part to read the data from an HTML input which has the runat="server" tag?

Here is the field:

```
<script>
    function readfield() {
        PageMethods.readfield(readfieldc);
    }
    function readfieldc(texte) {
        alert(texte);
    }
</script>
<asp:label id="myfield" runat="server" />
<input type="button" onclick="readfield()" value="submit" />
```

And the C# code:

```
[Webmethod()]
public static void readfield()
{
    return Request["myfield"]; //This line is what I want to achieve
}
```

I actually have no idea of what code to use to do this

Help would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up using JQuery serializeArray which does exactly that

Comment: If you accept your own answer, I think it's wise to elaborate on what you did exactly. Right now, we're looking at just some loose ends.

Answer (score 1):

if this is just using a standard postback then you should be able to use Response.Forms (with the current way you are creating the inputs)

```
var myField = Request.Form["myField"];
```

if you are using this using client side (via JavaScript) and want to pass this to the web method i would read this:

http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

You could also add runat="server"

```
<input name="myfield" id="myfield" value="" runat="server" />
```

or make this field a completely server side control

```
<asp:TextBox id="myField" runat="server"/>
```

then in your function you could access it as:

```
public static void readfield()
{
    var myValue = myValue.text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following example which should explain what you are trying to achieve
It is not 100% clear what you are trying to achieve but I feel this link should assist.
This should count for static or normal method in the web service.

[Asp.net WebService or Creating and Consuming WebService in asp.net or Create and call webservice in asp.net or how to create webservice and how to use webservice in asp.net](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/05/aspnet-web-service-or-creating-and.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `runat="server"`:

```
<input name="myfield" id="myfield" value="" runat="server"/>
```